# Take twice photos with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app I'm taking a picture by using the UIImagePickerController, when the picture is taken the app shows an another view controller in which I give to the user possibility to add a farm to his picture. In this view controller I will give to the user the chance to retake picture, so I created a button to recall the UIImagePickerController, I used the following code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonRetakePic:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark imagePicker delegate
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Immagini"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:imagePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    }

    NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:imagePath error:nil];
    long count = [fileList count];
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Nivea_%ld.jpg", count++];
    NSString *imagePathWithFileName = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:filename forKey:@"Filename"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    UIImage *picture = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSData *thumbData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 1);
    [thumbData writeToFile:imagePathWithFileName atomically:YES];

    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Picture"];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:vc];
}
```

But when I press on the buttonBack it shows me the UIImagePickerController with old picture and I can take picture without see what's going on the camera. Why it doesn't work? What's wrong? There's another way to retake picture? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First dismiss the imagePickerController that was previously presented. Then in completion try presenting new imagePickerController.

Comment: No problem I also struggled in same thing many times before :)

Answer (score 1):

You are just recalling your UIImagePicker, it will not open a new one. You will have to discard the data that you have received. Or do a reload data.